# Left join causing headache

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I am troubleshooting a process that is running a very long time, This select statemet  runs for over 30 minutes, when i comment out various parts of it, it runs very fast. i have put a * next to the Tables that appear to be causing the issue , the one with two ** has a clustered index on Empid and ChangeDate(these columns are not next to each other) not sure if that matters, also none of these tables has more than 3000 rows. I am hoping there is some simple tweak hat needs to be made. Is there something i should look at in source tables? any suggestions would be appreciated. i have googled 'multiple out joins in single statement' with no luck. For troubleshooting purposes i put the with(nolock) in.

```
select 
je.EmpID, 
max(med.ChangeDate) as Max_Medical_ChangeDate,  
max(den.ChangeDate) as Max_Dental_ChangeDate,
max(k.ChangeDate) as Max_401K_ChangeDate,
max(ltd.ChangeDate) as Max_LTD_ChangeDate,
max(std.ChangeDate) as Max_STD_ChangeDate,
max(life.ChangeDate) as Max_Life_ChangeDate,
max(sal.ChangeDate) as Max_Salary_ChangeDate,
max(ltdexe.ChangeDate) as Max_LTDEXE_ChangeDate
max(accid.ChangeDate) as Max_Accid_ChangeDate,
max(cancr.ChangeDate) as Max_Cancr_ChangeDate,
max(hosp.ChangeDate) as Max_Hosp_ChangeDate
from Judge_Emp je WITH(NOLOCK)
           left join Medical med on je.EmpID = med.EmpID 
           left join Dental den on med.EmpID = den.EmpID 
           left join R401K k on den.EmpID = k.EmpID 
           left join STDIns std on k.EmpID = std.EmpID 
           left join LTDIns ltd on std.EmpID = ltd.EmpID 
        *   left join LTDEXEIns ltdexe on ltd.EmpID = ltdexe.EmpID 
      **   left join LifeIns life on ltdexe.EmpID = life.EmpID 
        *  left join Salary sal on life.EmpID = sal.EmpID 
       left join AF_Accid accid on accid.EmpID=sal.EmpID
       left join AF_Cancr cancr on cancr.EmpID=accid.EmpID
       left join AF_Hosp hosp on hosp.EmpID=cancr.EmpID
group by je.EmpID
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "for troubleshooting purposes I put the with(nolock) in"?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

If you are using `left outer join`s, your join conditions should refer to the first table in the chain.  For instance:

```
from Judge_Emp je WITH(NOLOCK)
           left join Medical med on je.EmpID = med.EmpID 
           left join Dental den on je.EmpID = den.EmpID 
           left join R401K k on je.EmpID = k.EmpID  . . .
```

Rather than:

```
from Judge_Emp je WITH(NOLOCK)
           left join Medical med on je.EmpID = med.EmpID 
           left join Dental den on med.EmpID = den.EmpID 
           left join R401K k on den.EmpID = k.EmpID . . .
```

The reasons is that `med.EmptID` could be `NULL`, which would cause the join to fail.  (It doesn't make a difference for inner joins).

This probably doesn't affect the performance of the query, though.  My guess is that these have multiple matching rows and are generating a Cartesian product for each customer.